# Entity Framework 6 mapping issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been using EF for a while, but with just basic normalized tables, and little-to-no relationships between them. Now I'm looking to branch out and running into some mapping issues, that I'm sure are just solved by some simple `OnModelCreating()` changes, or additional model properties.

I'm creating a website to manage events that can occur at various locations. Each event is an entity. Each event has some basic primitive properties, but it also has a virtual `ICollection<TimeSlot>`.

```
    public virtual ICollection<TimeSlot> TimeSlots
    {
        get { return mTimeSlots ?? (mTimeSlots = new Collection<TimeSlot>()); }
        set { mTimeSlots = value; }
    }
```

`TimeSlot` is pretty simple too, it's supposed to represent a container for a collection of activities to occur at a particular time.

```
public class TimeSlot
{
    private ICollection<TimeSlotItem> mItems;

    public virtual ICollection<TimeSlotItem> Items
    {
        get { return mItems ?? (mItems = new Collection<TimeSlotItem>()); }
        set { mItems = value; }
    }

    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Since EF can't map to collections of primitive type (string in this case), I created another entity called `TimeSlotItem`, which is simply a string entity mapping.

```
public class TimeSlotItem
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is how to map this all together. EF doesn't map these correctly by default, as when I seed my database with some events, timeslots, and timeslotitems, it simply only maps everything to one of the events (the first one), and none of the others. I don't think the foreign keys are setup to map correctly. It's probably not doing a many-to-many at the moment, but it should, at least I believe.

My mapping is:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<FaroEvent>()
            .HasMany(f => f.TimeSlots);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TimeSlot>()
            .HasMany(f => f.Items);
    }
```

Lazy loading is enabled in the ctor.

My seed is:

```
    protected override void Seed(MyEventsDataContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        var timeSlotItems = new List<TimeSlotItem>
        {
            new TimeSlotItem {Description = "Do stuff 1"},
            new TimeSlotItem {Description = "Do stuff 2"},
            new TimeSlotItem {Description = "Do stuff 3"},
        };
        timeSlotItems.ForEach(t => context.TimeSlotItems.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Description, t));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var timeSlots = new List<TimeSlot>
        {
            new TimeSlot
            {
                Label = "Slot 1",
                Items = new Collection<TimeSlotItem> {timeSlotItems[0], timeSlotItems[1], timeSlotItems[2]}
            },
            new TimeSlot
            {
                Label = "Slot 2",
                Items = new Collection<TimeSlotItem> {timeSlotItems[0], timeSlotItems[1], timeSlotItems[2]}
            },
            new TimeSlot
            {
                Label = "Slot 3",
                Items = new Collection<TimeSlotItem> {timeSlotItems[0], timeSlotItems[1], timeSlotItems[2]}
            },
        };
        timeSlots.ForEach(t => context.TimeSlots.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Label, t));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var events = new List<MyEvent>
        {
            new MyEvent
            {
                Address = "123 Street Ln",
                CampaignId = "abc123",
                City = "City",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                EventDate = DateTime.Now,
                EventType = "TradeShow",
                Name = "Show Name",
                ProductInterest = "MyArm",
                State = "State",
                Zipcode = "12345",
                TimeSlots = new Collection<TimeSlot> {timeSlots[0], timeSlots[1], timeSlots[2]}
            },
            new MyEvent
            {
                Address = "123 Street Ln",
                CampaignId = "abc123",
                City = "City",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                EventDate = DateTime.Now,
                EventType = "TradeShow",
                Name = "Show Name",
                ProductInterest = "MyArm",
                State = "State",
                Zipcode = "12345",
                TimeSlots = new Collection<TimeSlot> {timeSlots[0], timeSlots[1], timeSlots[2]}
            },
            new MyEvent
            {
                Address = "123 Street Ln",
                CampaignId = "abc123",
                City = "City",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                EventDate = DateTime.Now,
                EventType = "TradeShow",
                Name = "Show Name",
                ProductInterest = "MyArm",
                State = "State",
                Zipcode = "12345",
                TimeSlots = new Collection<TimeSlot> {timeSlots[0], timeSlots[1], timeSlots[2]}
            },
        };
        events.ForEach(t => context.MyEvents.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Name, t));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: The seed method seems to expect many-to-many associations, but your model has one-to-many. What should it be?

Comment: Yes I believe that is the problem. I'm guessing to create the many-to-many my models should have references back to a list of the other entities.

Comment: Yes Gert, this was it. If you make this into an answer, I can mark it as correct (just needed each model to actually represent its own many-to-many relationship).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FaroEvent>().HasMany(f => f.TimeSlots).WithMany(f => f.Items);
```

You can find a better explanation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ManyToMany

Comment: This will not work in my case, as Items does not have many Events, and the mapping here enforces that it does.

Answer (score 1):

To get a better understanding of Fluent APIs and understand how do you have to map your entities, I used to use the [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d), or [Entity Framework Reverse Code-First POCO Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838) tools and let the tool generates the classes for me after I define what my table should look like in SQL database. this approach can help you start with the Fluent API and get a better understanding.

Hope that helps.